# Signup Verification

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, verification

Every time I leave any textbox unfilled for the 1st time, it would be registered to the db same as if I leave all the textboxes empty but when you do it for the 2nd time (any of the two), that would be the time the alert box would pop-up... I don't what to do.
Help me please.
Here's my code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 0);
$email= $_POST['email'];
$user= $_POST['user'];
$password= $_POST['password'];
$image =($_FILES['image']['name']);
$submit= $_POST['submit'];

if (empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($user) ) 
{
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    alert('You did not complete all of the required fields');
    window.location='blah2.php';
    </script>";  
}


if(isset($submit))
{   
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "top")
        or die('error in connection'.mysqli_connect_error());

        $q = "SELECT username , email FROM registries WHERE username = ? OR email = ?";     
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare ($con, $q);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $user, $email);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $user , $email);
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);

    if($result > 0) 
    { 
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
              alert('Email address or Username is already taken. Please pick another one.');
              window.location='blah2.php';
              </script>";       
    }   
    else
    {

        $q="INSERT INTO registries VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $q);
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"uploads/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssss', $email, $user, $password, $image);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

                header('Location: blah.php');


    }   

}
```

Comment: It is a little unclear what you're asking, can you give a better example (of what happens now, and what the intended functionality should be)?

Comment: @TylerAndFriends If I would try to press the 'done' button without filling up one of the textbox or perhaps all of the textbox for the very 1st try, it would register to the db instead of the alertbox poping up and telling the user that they left the textboxes empty. But when i repeat it again, that's the time the code would work properly. I would like to know how to make this code to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with this

```
$submit= $_POST['submit'];
```

`$submit` is always set

maybe you could try

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
```

and for debugging purpose you could try to `var_dump $email`, `$password` and `$user` and check if maybe they are really empty when you post your form once or twice

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right then just move

```
if(isset($submit)){
```

on top of your code right after

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```